# Bash if statement not working properly

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, arguments

I have a bash statement to test a command line argument. If the argument passed to the script is "clean", then the script removes all .o files. Otherwise, it builds a program. However, not matter what is passed (if anything), the script still thinks that the argument "clean" is being passed.

```
#!/bin/bash
if test "`whoami`" != "root" ; then
    echo "You must be logged in as root to build (for loopback mounting)"
    echo "Enter 'su' or 'sudo bash' to switch to root"
    exit
fi
ARG=$1
if [ $ARG=="clean" ] ; then
    echo ">>> cleaning up object files..."
    rm -r src/*.o
    echo ">>> done. "
    echo ">>> Press enter to continue..."
    read
else
    #Builds program
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the arguments to `[` with spaces; also, the equality operator is a single `=`, and you should quote both sides:

```
if [ "$ARG" = "clean" ]; then
```

Comment: It's better to swap those values. Putting the literal on the lefthand side can help to avoid issues in some shells w/ expansions to `test -option`.